# One function to recieve variables from many other functions

Tags: javascript

I 'm dealing an issue with some functions in javascript.
So i have this example

```
function(something) {
   var example = 1;
   var example2 = 2;    
            NameReturn(nameBusinessID, function(no) {
                    console.log(no);
                    //here is one callback value from another function

                });
            typeReturn(object, function(na) {
                    console.log(na);
                   //here is also a callback value from another function
                }); 
      view(example, example2);  
}   
function vliew(example, example2) {  
   console.log(example, example2);
   //but here i want also to console.log the variables "no" and "na"
}
```

So this is my issue, is there any way to achieve what i want??

I have no idea how to make those two variables, "no" and "na" to pass them to the function "view" 
Could anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the dirty way

```
    function(something) {
   var example = 1;
   var example2 = 2;    
            NameReturn(nameBusinessID, function(no) {
                    console.log(no);
                    //here is one callback value from another function
                    typeReturn(object, function(na) {
                        console.log(na);
                   //here is also a callback value from another function
                     view(example, example2,no, na);  
                  });
                });


}   
function vliew(_example, _example2,_no,_na) {  
   console.log(_example)
   console.log(_example2)
   console.log(_no)
   console.log(_na)

}
```

**UPDATE**

I have slightly modified your use case and implimented again.you can check code in this .

i am listening for button click callbacks and updating values in common object.once all four values are available,im calling the view function.

click both buttons and you will see result.

```js
function collector() {
  this.counter = 0;
  this.obj = {};
  this.setValues = function(name, value) {
    this.counter++;
    this.obj[name] = value;
    if (this.counter == 4) {
      view(this.obj.example, this.obj.example2, this.obj.no, this.obj.na);
    }
  };


}

function view(example, example1, a, b) {
  $('.result').append('example :' + example + '<br>');
  $('.result').append('example2 :' + example1 + '<br>');
  $('.result').append('na :' + a + '<br>');
  $('.result').append('no :' + b + '<br>');
}

function load() {

  var example = 1;
  var example2 = 2;
  var valueCollector = new collector();

  $('.no').on('click', function() {
    var no = 3;
    valueCollector.setValues('no', no);
  });
  $('.na').click(function() {
    var na = 4;
    valueCollector.setValues('na', na);
  });
  valueCollector.setValues('example', example);
  valueCollector.setValues('example2', example2);

}

load();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="no">no</button>
<button class="na">na</button>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: I want all the 4 variables to be passed at view function!

Comment: Ok it works but not completly good, the 2 functions from call back have to stay seperate!!
You have the one inside the other but i want it to be like this

`NameReturn(nameBusinessID, function(no) {
                    console.log(no);
                    //here is one callback value from another function
});
                    typeReturn(object, function(na) {
                        console.log(na);
                   //here is also a callback value from another function
                });`

Comment: It says "example3 is not defined" :/